# What is wrong with my case when statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, case-when

Background Summary: I have a date field called effectivedate, the format is YYYY-MM-DD. I am creating a new date column called Acct_Dt, the format is MM-YY. To give an idea of what a result should be, If I had an effective date of 2019-02-20. If the month and day(s) of that date fall between the 2019-02-16 and 2019-03-15 that means the new Acct_Dt will be 03-01.To match the old date format with the new date format of just MM-DD I am using the Right function to grab the month and day numbers.

If I had an effective date of 2019-06-15. If the month and day(s) of that date fall between the 2019-05-16 and 2019-06-15 that means the new Acct_Dt will be 06-01.

I am attempting to write a nested Case when statement to do this for all months of the year (Excluding the 2019-12-16 to 2020-01-15 transition. I haven't written logic for this).

Code below:

```
Select PolicyNumber
,EffectiveDate
,Case When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '01-16' and '02-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-02-01' 
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '02-16' and '03-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-03-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '03-16' and '04-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-04-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '04-16' and '05-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-05-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '05-16' and '06-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-06-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '06-16' and '07-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-07-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '07-16' and '08-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-08-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '08-16' and '09-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-09-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '09-16' and '10-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-10-01'
      When Right(EffectiveDate,5) BETWEEN '10-16' and '11-15' Then Acct_Dt = '-11-01'
      Else null
    End
FROM dbo.Combined_SS_RateMonitor
ORDER BY Policy_Number
```

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression** and it returns a Scalar Value. All of yours are trying to return a boolean result. Without knowing what you are trying to achieve here though, the actual syntax you're after is difficult to guess.

Comment: Also, there's no need for `ELSE NULL` in a `CASE` expression; if none of the `WHEN` clauses are true then `NULL` will be returned.

Comment: @JohnnyHammersticks . . . What is the data type of your "date field"?

Comment: @Larnu What I am trying to achieve is, based on the conditional statements I want to return a value in my new Acct_dt column in the MM-DD format

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using string logic on a `date` column?

```
select (case when day(EffectiveDate) <= 15
             then dateadd(day, 1 - day(EffectiveDate), EffectiveDate)
             else dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(EffectiveDate))
        end)
```

Comment: I'd assume his "date" column isn't a date column?  I'd agree with where you're going with this statement.

Comment: @TinyHaitian . . . Based on the first two sentences, I would not make that assumption:  "I have a **date field** called effectivedate, . . . I am creating a new **date column** called Acct_Dt".  Admittedly, the OP is talking about formats, but I think that is just confusion on how dates are actually stored.

Comment: Missed it, but good point.   I tried to update your code for a missed closing parenthesis after the "Then" clause of the case statement.  I can't update it though, as I need to update at least 6 characters.  :)  I didn't want to go completely redo your post.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I realized my data type was set to int and not date....changed that as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried to enter your code into a query but there seems to be an error with the else syntax

Comment: @JohnnyHammersticks . . . A closing paren was missing in the `then` clause.